# What are project managing, task/issue/time tracking web apps are available for free or at least cheap enough?

Tags: project-management

I am looking for a web application, which I can install on my server for purposes of project managing, time/issue/tasks tracking. It has to be either free or cheap enough for personal use (or up to 3 people).

I am already considering RubyMine, but I have a little troubles with setting it up on my Windows7 box.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.redmine.org/

you could give this one a try, it covers most things you might need.

Comment: It looks like I will test drive redmine and teambox to make my final decision. 

Thanks for mentioning on of these!

Comment: I'll add my +1 to redmine, the responses from StackOverflow suggest its better than Trac nowadays, but I guess that depends what features you need - Trac is definitely a good contender too.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the usage of **[Teambox](http://teambox.com/)** which has a twitter-like experience for project management. It is open-source and you can install it freely on your server.

Comment: It looks like I will test drive redmine and teambox to make my final decision. 

Thanks for mentioning on of these!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) as a issue/bug tracker tool, it is very similar to redmine (or so I have heard, never tried redmine). It supports integration with MediaWiki and SVN, which together is quite a powerful combination.

Have a look at [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) if you are looking for a personal todo list manager. It is the best todo manager out there, and well worth its cost.

Comment: +1 for trac _` ` ` `_

Answer (score 2):

We've been using [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) for a few months and have found it quite good.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of http://www.trackmyhours.com.

They are always updating based on user requests, and since they aren't a huge player, the guys who run it seems to respond to feature requests quickly and efficiently. We currently manage 3 consultants, and 6 employees using the software, not sure if its effective for bigger teams than that... but definitely worth a free trial.

I believe they have iPhone/android apps too, if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: Note: It isn't an installed solution - we use fogbugz for that - however TMH works better for the time issues.

Answer (score 2):

For the mentioned [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) and [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org), you can make use as well of the free [Bitnami installers](http://bitnami.org) to set them up easily.

Answer (score 1):

LiquidPlanner is a hosted solution, so you have nothing to install on your web servers. LiquidPlanner is an excellent option for task & team management, collaboration & time tracking. LiquidPlanner is simple enough for all of your team members to use, and also comes with a free iphone app.

http://www.liquidplanner.com/

Answer (score 0):

looked into [ProjectPier](http://www.projectpier.org/)? It's a free, self-hosted alternative to Basecamp

Answer (score 0):

I vote Unfuddle (www.unfuddle.com). More detail in another question: [Free/cheap defect tracking system (think bugzilla)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/free-cheap-defect-tracking-system-think-bugzilla)

Comment: Does Unfuddle allow itself to be installed on my own server?

Comment: I am not sure. To install on your own server, you could try Mantis or Bugzilla. We've used Mantis in the past and it's pretty good for small teams.

Comment: Unfuddle is a hosted service and cannot be installed on your own server.

Comment: That's bad, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ToBeeDo](http://www.tobeedo.com/) especialy if you like Gmail and other Google products and want something different that Basecamp and its clones. (Just to be clear — I'm a founder of [ToBeeDo](http://www.tobeedo.com/))

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I checked it out, but it does not seem to fit my requirements...

Answer (score 0):

There is [PoP Project](http://www.mypopproject.com) which is nice for oversight on current projects and knowledge transfer on old archived projects.  It is in a free Beta mode till next year so it is free to pilot a small project on there and see if you like it.

By the way, I am glad you are focused on web based project management.  For us, going web based project management was so convincing that we created a Youtube cartoon that shows why it is so great: youtube.com/watch?v=1DA6DHfiDvE

Answer (score 0):

You should give [Review19.com](http://review19.com) a try. It's extremely simple and easy to use, automatically syncs real-time among your project team and is completely free and unrestricted.

Apart from project / tickets management, it supports in-browser video conferencing as well which is perfect for geographically distributed teams.

Answer (score -1):

We use binfire.com, it is a great [project management application](http://www.binfire.com/) and a free version is available too (limited in numbers of collaborators, projects)

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation withe the mentioned service, otherwise your answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!