# Free/cheap defect tracking system (think Bugzilla)

Tags: webapp-rec

As a small-scale software developer, I need to track bugs and feature requests. Of course I could write something like this myself, or use something like Bugzilla, but my users probably feel my time is best spent on other things - such as actually fixing the bugs and adding the features. :)

I would love a low-cost option (this is a hobby that costs more than it makes), if possible with these features, in priority from most important at the top:

- Rock solid
- Issues a ticket number for each registered issue
- Support for multiple projects
- Possibility for discussion and research on each issue
- Nice, clean, simple, elegant design
- Possible to appear to be part of my site, i.e. set up DNS CNAME record so bugtracker.mysite.com points to my projects on the application provider site

I know I am probably asking for too much, but it **is** the web and 2010, so I should feel entitled to other people's work for free or cheap. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys - I'll be evaluating these to see which one is best for me!

Comment: If your project is open source, you have plenty of free options like Google Project Hosting.

Comment: Does this belong more on Stack Overflow than here? At least it deserves a cross-post if nothing else.

Answer (score 10):

Have you considered the [fogbugz student & startup edition](https://shop.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/default.asp?sCategory=HOSTEDFB&sStep=stepEnterEmailAddress&HFBnForm=1)?

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look to [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira), it's not Free but very cheap for small number of users (10$ for 10 users)

Answer (score 4):

We use Unfuddle ([www.unfuddle.com](http://www.unfuddle.com)) and its great. It's rock solid, supports multiple projects, issues a ticket number for every new ticket, allows discussion (via comments and 'notebooks') and has a simple and a clean design. In addition to all this, its only $9 for the smallest paid plan which allows 4 active projects and 10 developers. Their free plan, AFAIK, allows only one active project. They also support subversion and Git hosting. All in all, this has worked out great for us so far. I am not sure about your last concern though.

You could also try Pivotal Tracker ([www.pivotaltracker.com](http://www.pivotaltracker.com)) - its completely free and take a very different approach towards issue tracking in general. You may want to check that out as well.

We found [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) too expensive (thought it was pretty neat). The [student and startup edition](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/StudentAndStartup.html) allows only two users - if that works for you, I think FogBugz addresses all your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

We use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) at work, and it does all the things that you have set out above, with the added bonus of integrating with subversion and other source controls programs.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org), it's very close to JIRA and free.

Answer (score 0):

[ClockingIt](http://clockingit.com) seems to be a perfect match.

Comment: Is it a defect tracking system? Not sure visitors can enter new bugs with this app.

Comment: not arbitrary users. they must login and then they can create tasks (which you can categorize to "bugs")

Answer (score 0):

We tested a few open source options a few years ago and settled on redmine (http://www.redmine.org/); we've been very happy with the results.

I also recommend having a look at gforge: http://gforge.org/gf/.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/)

I am using it more than 2 years, and fully satisfied.

Comment: can you provide more context around why this is a good solution to the question asked? what parts of the original questions bullet list does assembla cover?

Answer (score 0):

We use Elementool.com.

Works well and allows us to work with outside vendors easily. Also has plugins for Visual Studio IDE so that tickets and tracking are incorporated into our dev environment.

John