# What web-based software combines bug tracking, agile project management and client collaboration?

Tags: collaboration, project-management, bug-trackers, basecamp, fogbugz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are project managing, task/issue/time tracking web apps are available for free or at least cheap enough?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2662/what-are-project-managing-task-issue-time-tracking-web-apps-are-available-for-fr)

I'm aware of really good packages that handle each one individually:
1. Bug tracking: Trac, Mantis, JIRA, FogBugz
2. Agile Project Management: Version One, Pivotal Tracker
3. Client Collaboration: Basecamp, activeCollab

But I haven't seen anything out there that handles all three things very well.

We've been slowly building our own system over the past 3 years, but I'd like to know: Is there a definitive web app already out there that combines these three things nicely?

Comment: Try to take a look at this one http://agilewalkthrough.com/

Answer (score 0):

Axosoft's OnTime actually handles the three things you mentioned quite nicely.

Bug Tracking - OnTime started out as a bug tracker
Agile Project Management - Had built-in Agile features like a burndown charts and a scrum planning board.
Collaboration - Has a customer portal for clients to submit tickets, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com), which handles these quite nicely. It has helpdesk mode for clients, bug / issue tracking and agile tools.

They also have a good [pdf](http://www.geminiplatform.com/e-book) about how to configure your system.